# Strange style conversion indicator appeared when type "a Pre"

Tags: conversion

I got the following strange style conversion indicator when I was typing `a Pre`(character `a` and `Pre` separated by a space) in an input cell:

[image]

I have no clue why it was triggered <s>and I don't even know this kind of conversion indicator is possible</s>.

So is it a potential bug? Or can you explain this behavior?

Configuration informations:

Mathematica version: 10.0.1

Operating system: Windows 8.1

---

Edit: Now I realized that it is possible to convert the style of a cell by literally typing `Convert to ...`in an input cell. But can you enlighten me where this feature is documented?

Comment: From http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CodeAssistOptions.html it looks like the option is "AutoConvertEnable".

Comment: Please apply the `bugs` tag only after there is confirmation or at least consensus that an issue is in fact a bug.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, I will remember that.

Comment: That's OK.  It helps to read the pop-up description on tags; in this case it reads: *"This tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions."*

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, got it. Thanks for the tip!